# Error : class could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout

I copied some java and XML files from another project (since my friend did the layout, but i do the core coding, and we do in different project)

Somehow when i implement the layout to my codes it give the error (class could not be instantiated), i fixed all the package path, refreshed it, cleaned it, making sure that the constructor is public (obviously), but the XML still gives me the error.

The project somehow works well after i restart my eclipse, it runs without any fail and no error in logcat, but it keeps give me the error when i check the friend_schedule.xml file in my eclipse files, but still it gives me curiousity if it'll give any effect later, any idea?

Here's the java file that can't be instantiated :

```
package cal.endar;
public class FriendSchedule extends LinearLayout 
{
public FriendSchedule(Context con)
{
    super(con);
    initComponent(con);
}

public FriendSchedule(Context con, AttributeSet att)
{
    super(con, att);
    initComponent(con);
}

public void initComponent(Context con)
{
    LayoutInflater inf=LayoutInflater.from(con);
    View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.main, null,false);

    //View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.daily_layout, null,false);
    //View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.weekly_layout, null,false);
    addView(v);
    v.getLayoutParams().height=LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    lp.weight=1;
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_list_selected);
}
}
```

And this is my friend_schedule.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="My Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
 </LinearLayout>

<cal.endar.FriendSchedule
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the XML as well? Make sure the package of the class is the same.

Comment: @kioels: edit your post with full code of FriendSchedule including pacage names and xml

Comment: edited with XML code as well, and of course with FriendSchedule package name... thx for the respond btw...

Answer (score 0):

i restarted my eclipse once more and the project managed to run well without any error (i don't know why this happened and i don't have any good specified answer for this)

but anyway, thanks for your response...